# Setting properties not displayed in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC project I have three links on the "Index" page which all launch the same "Create" view.  I would like to pass a flag to the view that allows me to determine which of the links was used to launch the view.

I have achieved this by creating a new instance of my class, setting the "mode" property and passing the model to the view.

For example, in the "Index" view I have:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Link 1", "Create", New With {.id = 1}, Nothing)
@Html.ActionLink("My Link 2", "Create", New With {.id = 2}, Nothing)
@Html.ActionLink("My Link 3", "Create", New With {.id = 3}, Nothing)
```

The "Create" in my controller would be:

```
Function Create(id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim myObject As myObject = New myObject
    myObject.Mode = id

    Return View(myObject)
End Function
```

This only seems to work if I have an editor in my view that references the "Mode" property.  If I leave the following code in my view everything works fine however if remove it (because I do not want to display it on the form) the "Mode" property is always set to 0.

```
<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Mode)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Mode)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Mode)
</div>
```

How can I set the "Mode" without displaying it in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model.Mode)
```